# Facebook: Mark a message as "TODO"

Tags: facebook, facebook-tags

When I open Facebook, I sometimes have 5 people asking me questions, and I usually don't have time to answer them all on-the-spot.

How can I "mark" a message so that later I remember that I have to answer it?

Usually I wait until the message is sent to my email inbox (where I can "star" it), but:

- The email usually does not come immediately
- The email does not come if I read the message on Facebook, so I can't read it (I can just see the first few lines)
- Sometimes the email is just not sent at all, even though I haven't touched it on Facebook.

I could create a browser bookmark for each message to answer, but it is not very convenient.
I could also mark the message as "unread", but actually many of the messages in my FB inbox are "unread", because I don't check the messages I have already received by email... so I can't use this trick either.
Any better option?

Answer (score 2):

When I have an inbox that I need to take care of regularly (Facebook, StackOverflow, physical mailbox) I make a recurring task to check and clear out that inbox. So you could as a workaround make a task in your normal to-do list to "Answer Facebook messages" every day or week, and answer them all then.

You could also use Quicksilver to create a custom script to save selected FB message text as a To Do, or to send that text to you as an email.

Comment: The problem is to know which message needs to be processed. Let's say I received 500 messages per week, and only 10 need to be "marked". Going through every single message once again would incur a huge time loss. The Quicksilver idea sounds interesting (even though I am on Ubuntu), is such a script readily available (or a script doing something very similar for inspiration)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you need in general is some sort of "Social CRM" tool, although at this point in time I do not have a specific recommendation for you.

A Social CRM tool that is well-integrated with Facebook (and other social media channels) should be able to, among its other capabilities, capture messages received via social media and create and manage corresponding tasks.